# Tkinter: how to clear Entry Widget and copy multiple notes to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, button, tkinter

My code currently is able to take text from an Entry Widget once the submit button is pressed and copy that information into a CSV file. I am having difficulty having the Entry Widget erase the text in the text box once the submit button is clicked. As well as this, I am trying to have multiple entries appear underneath each other after each submit, however, the code currently erases the previous text and replaces it with the newest submit. Below is the code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import csv

resultsFile= open("Results_Button_List.csv", "w")
namesWriter = csv.writer(resultsFile)
header = ["Notes"]
namesWriter.writerow(header)

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.output()

    def output(self):
        Label(text='Name:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.e = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.e.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)

    def writeToFile(self):
        with open("Results_Button_List.csv", "w") as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.e.get()])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Notes Section')
    root.geometry('1000x100')
    app=App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: either write data to `resultsFile` or open the file for appending `"a"` since when you open a file for writing it deletes the current content of the file.

Comment: make sure you `resultsList.close()` since it could be messing up the data when your program exits

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Thank you! It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the text box empty after the `Submit` button is pressed, add `self.e.delete(0, END)` at the end of the `writeToFile(self)` function.

To append the text to the file, set the file open mode to `a` (i.e. append). So, make the following changes:

<strike>`with open("Results_Button_List.csv", "w") as f:`</strike>

```
with open("Results_Button_List.csv", "a") as f:
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was working before, but now, the code does not save the information. Is there something I should add?

Comment: you must add the `self.e.delete(0, END)` after the end of the function, after it is written

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work again. Silly error I had. Thanks for your help!